# Purpose of Suspend Functions

Tags: android, kotlin

Why use suspend functions in the code below, can't the functions be run on another thread (not the main thread) even if they're not suspend functions?

```
@Dao
interface ItemDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(item: Item)

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun update(item: Item)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(item: Item)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM items")
    fun getAllItems(): Flow<List<Item>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = :itemId")
    fun getItem(itemId: Item): Flow<Item>
}
```

Comment: Yes, non-suspend functions can be called on another thread. But see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html and https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `suspend` modifier enforces you to call the function from a coroutine scope. Without it, you can call it without creating a coroutine scope. So if you accidentally call it from your Main thread, it will block your UI until it finishes executing.

So, with the suspend modifier, you have to do something like this:

```kotlin
// Create a Coroutine Scope
viewModelScope.launch {
    // Move to an I/O optimized thread
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        ItemDao.insert(item)
    }
}
```

Without the suspend function you can do this

```kotlin
// From the default thread (Will block UI)
// Or any other thread (Won't block UI)
ItemDao.insert(item)
```

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: So essentially they just make it more likely that you will call the function from another thread? Is that right?

Comment: In this case with Room, yes.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know Android Studio don't actually show you the warning but `room` library don't want to work on main thread and stop the main thread from rendering `View` so it will throw error when you will try to run it on main thread. Suspend keyword don't actually do anything other than prevent you from writing code that would potentially block your main thread and "freeze" your application since your IDE will highlight it and provide better support.

Answer (score 0):

> **Suspending functions** are at the center of everything coroutines. A
> suspending function is simply a function that can be paused and
> resumed at a later time. They can execute a long running operation and
> wait for it to complete without blocking.

If you do not use the suspend function, you will have to try different ways and techniques without blocking the main thread.